# How can I compute the nullspace of a matrix where the nullspace contains elements which are NON ZERO and WHOLE numbers

Tags: numpy, sympy, linear-algebra

First id like to say I know that some matrices will not be able to have a nullspace that fits my qualifications. Im looking for an algorithm that could produce a matrix with non zero whole integer values in the first columns of the nullspace matrix computed.

```py
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
N = np.array([[1], [1], [-2], [1], [1]]) # <==== i want to get a result like this

M = Matrix(A)
print(M * Matrix(N))
print(M.nullspace())
```

Output:

```
Matrix([[0], [0], [0], [0]])

[Matrix([
[ 1],
[ 0],
[-1],
[ 1],
[ 0]]), Matrix([
[ 0],
[ 1],
[-1],
[ 0],
[ 1]])]
```

I tried to get the nullspace of a matrix but the results were either 0 or non integer values.

Comment: If you make a random linear combination of the nullspace basis vectors then it will very likely satisfy your requirements if they are satisfiable.

Comment: Are there any situations where in which the addition of these columns would result in an element being zero when without the addition of the columns, say the first column would suffice my constraints?

Also what if I want the 1st entry in the nullspace to be exactly -1?

Comment: You can always check if any column already satisfies your constraints before doing anything else. If you want the first entry to be exactly -1 then you'll need to choose only linear combinations that satisfy that by looking at the first entries of all columns.